# Как найти картинки в sheet1.xml?

Tags: xml, excel, phpexcel, xls, xlsx

Задача: есть большой xlsx файл, в котором есть название позиции и прикреплена картинка. Надо всё это экспортировать. Пробовал работать через PHPExcel — ругается на большой файл.

Разрахивировал и в sheet1.xml (https://pastebin.com/XVJRw4Et) методом перебора выяснил, что картинка спрятана где-то тут:

```
786
```

Но при поиске в остальных файлах никак не удается сопоставить это с картинками в media. Как быть? :)

Comment: Через zip библиотеку можно вытащить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не осилил xml файлы, решил задачу макросом VB, который экспортирует картинки в папку и на их место пишет путь.

```
Sub Save_Object_As_Picture()
Dim li As Long, oObj As Shape, wsSh As Worksheet, wsTmpSh As Worksheet
Dim sImagesPath As String, sName As String

sImagesPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\images\" '"
If Dir(sImagesPath, 16) = "" Then
    MkDir sImagesPath
End If
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wsSh = ActiveSheet
Set wsTmpSh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
For Each oObj In wsSh.Shapes
    If oObj.Type = 13 Then
        li = li + 1
        oObj.Copy
        sName = "img" & li
        With wsTmpSh.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, oObj.Width, oObj.Height).Chart
            .ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = 0
            .Parent.Select
            .Paste
            .Export Filename:=sImagesPath & sName & ".jpg", FilterName:="JPG"
            .Parent.Delete
        End With
        oObj.TopLeftCell.Value = sName
        oObj.Delete 'удаляем картинку с листа
    End If
Next oObj
Set oObj = Nothing: Set wsSh = Nothing
wsTmpSh.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Объекты сохранены в папке: " & sImagesPath, vbInformation, "www.excel-vba.ru"
End Sub
```

Источник: http://www.excel-vba.ru/chto-umeet-excel/kak-soxranit-kartinki-iz-lista-excel-v-kartinki-jpg/

*Спасибо, @nick_n_a, дополнил*

Comment: VB макрос может не работать под линуксом, а php под линуксом работает.